# JSF 1.1 and tomahawk 1.1.1 inputCalendar, is myfaces-*.jar needed?

Tags: jsf, calendar, tomahawk

I should use JSF 1.1 Mojarra implemetnation in job project.

But I need a popUp calendar widget. I've tried many different frameworks and stopped on tomahawk. I've setupped filter for tomahawk javasripts in web.xml but still have problems.

Should I necessary replace jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jar with myfaces-impl.jar and myfaces-api.jar ?

Or can I work with some versions of tomahawk calendar without faces.jar ?

Maybe someone can advice some popup calendar widget for JSF 1.1 from other frameworks that can be easy integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I necessary replace jsf-impl.jar and jsf-api.jar with myfaces-impl.jar and myfaces-api.jar ?

No, that's not needed. Tomahawk is just a **component library** which is supposed to be JSF implementation independent. That it is created by the MyFaces guys is pure coincidence. I've used Tomahawk on Mojarra for ages and it works fine.

---

You should be more clear about those "problems" if you want more assistance. Ask a new question wherein you post the problem in depth detail (JSF/Tomahawk/Servletcontainer impl/version, steps done, unexpected results, any warnings/errors/exceptions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a date picker, you could use the pure javascript library, eg: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/DatePickerTest.htm

Answer (score 0):

Seams that this combination works with JSF 1.1 Mojarra implementations:

```
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
tomahawk-1.1.9.jar
```

And changes in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<!--
    extension mapping for adding <script/>, <link/>, and other resource
    tags to JSF-pages
-->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<!--
    extension mapping for serving page-independent resources (javascript,
    stylesheets, images, etc.)
-->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```